# Is it OK to name a training day "Learn Productname day"?

Tags: grammar

I need a help from English native speaker on below.

We are hosting some training sessions about some IT products.
The company which products we introduce and train people about, say Productname.

So would it be correct to name a training day about Atlassian products as "Learn Productname day"?

For me it sounds like to train about the day, not a product.

Would it sound better if it's something like "**Atlassian** training day" or something like that?

Thanks,
Natalia

Comment: When you say 'some products' I assume that there are a number of loosely related or unrelated products in the range, perhaps a word processor, a graphics package, a movie editor and so on. I find it difficult to believe that you can train people to _use_ a number of different products in one day, what I suspect you are doing is _introducing_ them to the products and explaining the advantages of Atlassian products over your competitors' products. Is this the case?

Comment: @BoldBen
Thanks for your question.
It's a day when we introduce all products of the company and teach how to use 2 products in details including practical exercise.

Comment: In that case I would call it "Learn _About_ Atlassian Day", "Atlassian Introduction Day" or "Atlassian Taster Day" as it does seem to be a day selling Atlassian products rather than producing Atlassian experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that phrase, *Learn Atlassian day*, is idiomatic.

The word **day** can be modified by a clause. Compare:

> Bring your Child to Work Day
>
> National Cut Your Energy Costs Day
>
> National Girl Hug Boy Day
>
> Kiss a Ginger Day
>
> National Clean Your Desk Day
>
> National Wear Red Day
>
> Shower With A Friend Day
>
> Read Across America Day
>
> National Be Heard Day
>
> National Let's Laugh Day

The clause is understood to function like an adjective. The day is a day on which the action of that clause is meant to be deliberately engaged in.

The day can happen once a year, monthly, or weekly, or at random or arbitrary times.

> Monday is our take out the garbage day.
>
> The fifteenth is our monthly clean out the office fridge day.
>
> We're going to have another clean up the playground day in the near future.

The pattern can be paraphrased like this:

> Monday is our day *to take out the garbage*.
>
> The fifteenth is our monthly day *to clean out the office fridge*.
>
> We going to have another day in the near future *to clean up the playground*.

Comment: @ TRomano, Thank you for your answer. I think now it's clear for me.